# How to see hidden audio files in audio CDs

Tags: windows-7, command-line, audio

I bought a audio CD yesterday. when I open it I see just some shortcuts and when I do a double-click on them they work fine and the music starts to play! 
[image]
*Note: My computer settings configured in a way that shows all hidden files and super hidden files(system files), But I can't see any other files as you see above*

When I did a right-click on the CD-drive and select ptroperties I see the below out put:
[image]

And even when I use `dir` command in **CMD** I can't see anything else except those shortcuts!

```
F:\>dir
 Volume in drive F is Audio CD
 Volume Serial Number is 00D2-6067

 Directory of F:\

01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track01.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track02.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track03.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track04.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track05.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track06.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track07.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track08.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track09.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track10.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track11.cda
              11 File(s)            484 bytes
               0 Dir(s)               0 bytes free

F:\>dir /A
 Volume in drive F is Audio CD
 Volume Serial Number is 00D2-6067

 Directory of F:\

01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track01.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track02.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track03.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track04.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track05.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track06.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track07.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track08.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track09.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track10.cda
01/01/1995  03:30 AM                44 Track11.cda
              11 File(s)            484 bytes
               0 Dir(s)               0 bytes free

F:\>
```

The question is that : how they hide the files? And how can I see the files? (A CMD command base is better than of a software.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, there are no real files on the disc—there are just bits, which represent pulse-code modulated audio. There is indeed a table of contents on the disc, but that's not what you see in Windows.

Windows shows you virtual files that do not really exist on the disc. They just tell the OS where on the disc a track starts. That's also the reason you can't copy the files, as they don't contain any audio data per se.

Read more about it [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Digital_Audio#Data_access_from_computers).

Comment: There is no any way to have those files on my computer? (Instead of on the compact disk)

Comment: Why peoples doesn't use this mechanism to store other data (for example `.exe`,`.pdf` files and so on) on a CD? What is the advantages and disadvantages of this method?

Comment: Well, if you want to have the CD audio on your computer, you can of course use any ripping software. The reason for not putting actual computer files on there is simple: the CD-audio specification is from 1980 or earlier. People didn't have PCs then, really. Today, it's much more convenient to use ISO 9660 filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is rather an easy one, users do this to keep their data safe from general public due to privacy or copyright reasons, but it can be easily bypassed using a software called IsoBuster. The software is pretty self explanatory and you don't need to be a techie to be able to use it. 
Here is a YouTube tutorial of it anyway : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykDST81vvYU&t=44s

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Essential information should be in the answer, not in a linked video. If you're recommending software, please  read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that the disk in the question is an Audio CD and not a data CD.

Answer (score 0):

With Linux it's possible, directly from file browser. CD Audio Files are WAV files, and you can copy them directly to HDD.